# How to use angular material theme color in TypeScript / JavaScript?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-ui, angular-material2

I don't know how to get the primary theme color (Angular Material) in a e.g. `component.ts`.

I can use `color="primary` in my `template.html` or `mat-color($primary)` in a `style.scss`. But how do I use theme colors for styling an element inside a canvas? **How do I use them inside my TypeScript-code**?

Info:

```
"@angular/material": "^5.0.0-rc.2",
"@angular/core": "^5.0.0"
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I used a hacky solution. It's not beautiful but working.

**component.html**

```
<div #primary class="mat-button mat-primary" style="display:none"></div>
```

**component.ts**

```
declare let getComputedStyle: any;

export class Component implements AfterViewInit {
    @ViewChild('primary') primary: ElementRef;

    ngAfterViewInit() {
       const primaryColor = getComputedStyle(this.primary.nativeElement).color;
    }
```

Comment: They should really make some kind of Palette object injectable into components so when we need to use libraries like Chart.js. Its easier to implement from material palettes. I'll be using this approach. Thanks :)

Comment: @Daniel Is it the `primaryColor` we use?? It show undefined when console log.

Comment: @surazzarus You should get a rgb color String. If not, check if you added the html code to your template and declared `getComputedStyle`.

Answer (score 4):

I used your solution as the base for this as I had multiple charts and components that needed to set colours in the js. hopefully this is more reusable and extendable when using multiple charts or third party js components that use colours and you want those colours to come from the Material theme or palettes.

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-theme-emitter',
    template: `<div class='primary'></div>
               <div class='accent'></div>
               <div class='warn'></div>`,
    styles: [':host { display: none; }']
})
export class ThemeEmitterComponent implements AfterViewInit {

    primaryColor: string;
    accentColor: string;
    warnColor: string;

    @ViewChild('primary') primaryElement: ElementRef;
    @ViewChild('accent') accentElement: ElementRef;
    @ViewChild('warn') warnElement: ElementRef;

     ngAfterViewInit() {
        this.primaryColor = getComputedStyle(this.primaryElement.nativeElement).color;
        this.accentColor = getComputedStyle(this.accentElement.nativeElement).color;
        this.warnColor = getComputedStyle(this.primaryElement.nativeElement).color;
     }
}
```

Created a _theme mixin and passed in the material theme in the scss.

```
@mixin theme-emitter($theme) {

    $primary: map-get($theme, primary);
    $accent: map-get($theme, accent);
    $warn: map-get($theme, warn);

    app-theme-emitter {
        .primary {
            color: mat-color($primary);
        }
        .accent {
            color: mat-color($accent);
        }
        .warn {
            color: mat-color($warn);
        }
    }
}
```

Inside your main.scss

```
...

$theme: mat-light-theme($primary-palette, $accent-palette, $warn-palette);
@include theme-emitter($theme);
```

Then inside the component you want to consume these colours from:

`<app-theme-emitter></app-theme-emitter>`

`@ViewChild(ThemeEmitterComponent) theme: ThemeEmitterComponent;`

This is working pretty well for me it seems, what do you think?

[*I submitted this as a feature request for Material2.*](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/11315)